# Sending email and adding a parameter to django admin registration

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two questions. both regarding the admin site of django

1. How to add an extra field to the auth_user model in django. That field has to appear in the default admin registration. Any snippet for that would help.

2.I do my registration using the default admin site. what should i do if i have to send a mail of registration. I have configured in my settings.py for sending mails, and

```
"send_mail('This is a test Subject', 'This is a test Mail', 'x@x.com',
    ['y@y.com'], fail_silently=False)"
```

the above code send the mail successfully.
Now when a new user is registered this should fetch the mail id form the database and send the mail with his/her username. How can i do this or any reference to such stuff should be helpful.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking, what exact problem are you experiencing?

Comment: @bouke hope it has some clarity now ??

Answer (score 0):

To override Django User model please follow below code.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.TextField()
```

If you want to send email after successful registration of django admin you should look Django signals.

please see below code it will help you to send email.

```
def send_email(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    #fetch email id from db and email sending code will be here
    post_save.connect(send_email, sender=User)
```